# Go to current executing statement in Visual Studio while Debugging

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, keyboard-shortcuts

While debugging in Visual Studio sometimes we wander far away from the current executing statement. We could tread our way back using Call Stack window. Is there a shortcut to go back to the current executing statement in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

In the Debug Context Menu, there's a "Show Next Statement" option that should do what you want.

If you've got the default General Development Settings applied, the default key binding for this is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Num *</kbd>. To see what it is in your settings, go to Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard, and find `Debug.ShowNextStatement`. You can, of course, also then change the key binding to one of your preference.

Answer (score 17):

Alt-* does take you to the current statement but it also shows you the disassembly. Use Alt-NUMERIC-*

Answer (score 7):

Keyboard short cut in Visual Studio to return to current execution statement, press ALT + *

Answer (score 1):

An easy way, if you don't have an easy way to hit Num* or your VS doesn't have show-next-statement in the menus (VS 2022?):  Show the call stack view and double-click the top (current) statement.