# Is there any way to check currently executing code in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

I've been working on a C# project and I don't know the program flow. I want to know all the executing codes in a particular flow. I can press the pause button to check current executing code, but to check entire flow, I need to keep on pressing `F11` or next line, which is cumbersome. BTW, I got it from here
[Find out what line of code my app is currently running in Visual Studio's debug mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508749/find-out-what-line-of-code-my-app-is-currently-running-in-visual-studios-debug)

I would like to know is there any way in visual studio to check currently executing code without pausing or placing break points?

Comment: How about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20901574/go-to-current-executing-statement-in-visual-studio-while-debugging) ?

Comment: No, I think you misunderstood, I want it to keep showing executing lines.

Comment: Oh! My mistake.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I often use the VS debugging breakpoint or debug menu options like "Step Into/Out" or use the pausing button.

But if you don't want to use them, the Runtime Flow tool is a workaround I know which can help you see code that is executed:

[Find out which line will be executed in Visual Studio debug mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31346496/find-out-which-line-will-be-executed-in-visual-studio-debug-mode?rq=1)

A feature request for VS IDE:

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/17332198-is-there-any-way-to-check-currently-executing-code

In VS2017, debug has a new feature called "Run execution to here", I know that it doesn't really meet your requirement, but it is a better workaround if you don't want to step Into debugging one step by one step. Move your mouse to the icon and click the button, now your code will run and stop on that line the next time it is hit in your code path.

[image]

Comment: Well, that is not free. Are there any free alternatives?

Comment: & Prajwal, I didn't find other tools, but I help you submit a feature request to the VS product team, you could vote it:)

Comment: @ Prajwal, could you help me vote that feature request? I also provide a VS2017 new function, if possible, you could check it. Maybe it is easy for app debugging than before even if it also doesn't show the code line as your requirement, but I think it could help us debugging app easily:)

Comment: I voted it. I'm checking out code map, even it is not what I really expected, but it is somewhat useful.

Comment: @Prajwal, if my reply is helpful for you, would you please mark it as the temporary answer? So other members could find the thread easily if they get the same issue, and then help us vote that feature request. Of course, the VS2017 new function is also could help other community members during debugging:) Have a nice day!

Comment: @JackZhaiMSFT, I will. I was checking a possible way of using Code map for this purpose. Till now I found none.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that there is code running but you don't know where and you want to see what is going on.  A good example is the code is stuck in a loop somewhere but you don't know where.

To break-into the running code:

**Option 1:** Select the **'Debug' menu item**, and then select the **'Break All' menu item**.

**Option 2:** Press keys **Ctrl+Alt+Break**.

This will break into the code where it is executing and you will step into debugging just as if you hit a breakpoint.

Happy debugging!

Comment: what is laptop keyboard doesn't have `Break` key? :)

Comment: The 'break' key may only be labelled as 'pause'. Most notebooks should have the 'pause' key or the equivalent function key.

Answer (score 0):

If you want this ability at debug time then consider [IntelliTrace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264915.aspx)

ReSharper has a [Call Tracking](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_analysis.html#Call_Tracking) feature that can display incoming and outgoing calls sequenced in an interactive, graphical tree view.

See if this helps.