# How to find out where dotnet app gets stuck?

Tags: c#, .net, raspberry-pi

I have a dotnet app, which I'm running on a Raspberry PI. I don't have a way to run full-fledged IDE on it, like Visual Studio or Rider. I run it on Raspberry PI with `dotnet run`. Since the app depends on some Raspberry PI hardware specifics, I cannot run it anywhere else.

I noticed that sometimes the app gets stuck somehow and the logs are no longer being generated. How can I find out which place in my code is the place where runtime is stuck? I don't see any exceptions. I can't even exit the app with SIGINT. I have to `kill -9` it.

Comment: Add some logging.

Comment: Well, that would work, but it also means I will have to first add a lot of code, and then remember to remove it.

Comment: There's a bit of overhead, yeah, but logging is helpful to have in pretty much any app for this very reason. And you wouldn't need to remove it. Many logging libraries exist that let you configure different log levels, which would allow you to turn it on/off as needed, and to not log sensitive info in production environments.

Comment: That's true, but too much log lines in the code make it difficult to read the code itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can publish your application in Debug configuration and use remote debugging via SSH (first of all you need to configure SSH on raspberry). More information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-dotnet-core-linux-with-ssh?view=vs-2022

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting. When I attach a debugger this way, how will I know where my app is in terms of code?

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately this works only with the Windows version of Visual Studio. Rider has the feature as well, potentially that will work.

Comment: @mnj maybe this answer can help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/40969604/7357322